# Cross-platform development on Mac using Xamarin/Visual Studio/Eclipse advice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, cross-platform

I recently bought a Lumia 950 on Windows 10 and want to develop some Universal Windows Apps, and I already got developed Android apps developed on Eclipse.

So, I would prefer to develop on my Mac (OS X 10.9.5) and cross-platform (I also got an iPhone 4S). In case of I really need to develop on Windows, I have a windows 10 Insider on a virtual machine, but I would prefer use it to test my apps. Also, develop Mac apps can be interesting.

I don't know if there is great Eclipse plug-in to do it, and as it is already a "gaz factory", I would prefer Xamarin, which seems much more adapted.

But I don't know which version to use, there is so much declination of this tool :

- [Xamarin Studio](https://www.xamarin.com/) (Mac OS compatible)
- [Visual Studio IDE](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (Mac OS compatible)
- [Visual Studio Comunity](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/)

**I have a lot of questions:**

1. What differences there is between those IDEs?
2. Can I use iOS/Android/Windows Mobile emulator on my environment?
3. Now that [Visual Studio includes Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/). Is it well integrated ?
4. Can I develop on my Mac ? or use my Windows 10 VM?
5. Can I deploy my apps on my Windows Mobile? On my iPhone? With debugging?

Thanks to make my mind clear :)

Comment: These are very broad questions. It might be best to read through the Xamarin documentation to come to a conclusion. https://www.xamarin.com/faq / https://developer.xamarin.com/

Comment: Visual Studio versions comparison: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What differences there are between those IDEs?

On Windows there are two choices for Xamarin app development.

**Visual Studio**
is the default choice for Xamarin on Windows. It has the most up-to-date support and should be most stable. Since Microsoft bought Xamarin, the platform became free for all developers, so you no longer need the paid Visual Studio IDE, but you can use Visual Studio Community.

**Xamarin Studio**
is the second choice, which also works great, but because of all the extensions and first-class support, Visual Studio is definitely a better choice.

On Mac you can use **Xamarin Studio** only. The app should be always on par with the Windows version.

If you really don't want to use Windows 10 (which is a great OS ;-) ), **Xamarin Studio** will probably suit your needs for iOS development. For UWP however, you will need to use Visual Studio on Windows as it is the only way to build UWP apps.

## Can I use iOS/Android/Windows Mobile emulator on my environment?

**Android** emulator is avaiable on both Mac and Windows, so you are covered there.

**iOS** Simulator runs only on Mac, so in case you use Xamarin Studio on Mac, it will run out of the box and if you use Visual Studio on Windows, you will need to connect to it using the built-in Visual Studio **Xamarin Mac Agent**. The newest versions of Visual Studio also have a preview of an awesome [Remote Simulator for iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/). With this, you can view the simulator directly on your PC and even use touch gestures to control it, which is normally impossible on Mac.

**UWP** has Emulators for Mobile and Simulator for desktop, you need to use Visual Studio on Windows 10 to run them (and build UWP apps).

## Visual Studio includes Xamarin. Is it well integrated?

Yes! As I have said above, it is a first-class experience!

## Can I develop on Mac?

You can develop iOS and Android apps on Mac, but need Windows with Visual Studio to build UWP apps.

## Can I deploy my apps on my Windows Mobile? On iPhone? On Android?

**On Mac you can debug Android and iOS apps** as well as test on a real device by connecting it and selecting it as the debug target.

**On Windows you can debug UWP and Android apps** on your devices and also **debug iOS apps** by connecting the Mac Agent as I have described above. Visual Studio and Mac Agent communicate very well with Mac, so it works great even with debugging on real iOS device :-) .

Hope this helps! Looking forward to your UWP and Xamarin apps :-) !